# what is the scoring variable called for aucpr?

Tags: classification, scikit-learn, scoring-rules, pre-training

i am trying to conduct a grid search for an imbalanced problem however i cannot find the aucpr (area under curve precision recall) scoring metric for gridsearch. e.g. you have 'roc-auc', 'neg-brier-loss' but what is the respective aucpr scoring method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scikit-learn` has a summary of the precision-recall curve called [average_precision_score](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score.html#sklearn.metrics.average_precision_score), which is similar to the aucpr, but is actually a rectangular approximation, see https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/52130/about-sklearn-metrics-average-precision-score-documentation